# A special user does not appear in Windows login screen

Tags: windows, login, user-management

In the list of users (under Local Users and Groups in my Windows 7) I have an ASPNET user (its description says "Account used for running the ASP.NET worker process (aspnet_wp.exe)" and its full name is "ASP.NET Machine Account")

The thing is this user does not appear in Windows login screen. What I have found:

- It is not a "Built-in security pricipal" user
- It belongs only to Users group
- I don't have `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts`  key in my registry

In every sense I can see that it is a normal user yet it does not appear in login screen. Now the questions are:

**What does make it special?**

**How can I create a user like this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is that it has the "Deny log on locally" user right.

Run `gpedit.msc` and go to Computer Configuration: Windows Settings: Security Settings: Local Policies: User Rights Assignment and find the "Deny log on locally" setting.  By default this contains the Guest account; I think in your case you will find it also contains the ASPNET account.

You can add additional accounts to this list by double-clicking on "Deny log on locally" and selecting "Add User or Group".